# Does `npm audit` add any value when using `dependabot`

Tags: security, node.js, dependency-management, npm

### Context

There are multiple ways to scan projects for vulnerabilities.

[Dependabot](https://dependabot.com/blog/javascript-security-updates/) can be configured to check repositories for issues, and automatically submits pull requests to resolve.

[NPM Audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit) will scan the packages used in an NPM solution for known vulnerabilities.

We're trying to work out whether, if Dependabot is enabled, there's any added value to using `NPM Audit` in our pipelines.  I'm asking this solely from the perspective of what's detected; not how the tools work (i.e. whether they can cause a pipeline to block/fail).

### The actual question

Do both tools base their decisions on some common known-issue database, or is it common to see each tool detect different sets of problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dependabot and `npm audit` both poll the [Node Security Working Group](https://github.com/nodejs/security-wg) database for Node-based projects. However, Dependabot has the added ability to check dependencies in [numerous other types of projects](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-dependabot-version-updates#supported-repositories-and-ecosystems) as well.

Also, each report Dependabot generates includes useful info and links directly to a GitHub Advisory Database listing (e.g., [CVE-2017-16021](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-333w-rxj3-f55r)) that itself has multiple links to other listings such as NIST. On the other hand, `npm audit`'s reporting is limited to a single link to an npm advisory listing with far less info (e.g., [#100](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/100)).

Overall, Dependabot covers all the bases — and more — that `npm audit` does. No need to use both unless you need a customized audit flow in your package scripts.

---

### Update

As of 7 October 2021, both methods provide info from the GitHub Advisory Database. From the links above, you can see that former npmjs.org listings now redirect to GitHub. The other points I made still stand after this change.

Answer (score 3):

As per October 2021:

**GitHub Advisory Database now powers npm audit** : "This means that every version of the npm CLI that supports security audits is now talking directly to the GitHub Advisory Database" - The GitHub Advisory Database is what powers  **Dependabot** and now also *npm audit*

https://github.blog/2021-10-07-github-advisory-database-now-powers-npm-audit/